Restricted – a cryptic crossword
This is part 62 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
Every clue in this cryptic crossword contains one extra word, which must be removed before solving. Read the first and last letters of the removed words in clue order to reveal how to find the final answer.
Today I have obtained a special permission to visit a city with a rich cultural history. I have seen ancient temples, palaces and monasteries, climbed endless flights of stairs, and engaged in some lengthy bargaining with friendly local street vendors. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Nobleman's unending expedition to populate Arctic planet (8)
6. Romeo originally named – before marriage, ultimately? (3)
7. Ivan who served serious purpose in the middle of rebellions (5)
8. Entities bound to be drawn (4)
10. Central European city's rodeo born to be wild (4)
12. Web lovers kiss behind Arthur Trudeau's back (5)
13. Younger water and wind coming from the east (3)
14. Tornado outflow violently takes front of farmhouse from one place to another (2,3,3)
Down
1. Somewhere in Canada, athlete guy goes against current on boat at sea (8)
2. Indigo caviar and pink wine – zero shillings! (3)
3. Obnoxious and perverted guy Umberto pinched girl's bottom (4)
4. Marine ranger brings on a notable random sample (5)
5. A risqué doodler scribbled to describe desirable destination (2,6)
9. She inspires poets to ingest sweet? Oh, that's about right (5)
11. One zone failed to hold ten farm animals (4)
13. Brits who fly a great distance to return radio (3, abbr.)

Gladys will return in When in Rome...

An excellent puzzle as always, Jafe! Gladys is visiting

Lhasa, Tibet

The filled grid is as follows:

 

And the clues (extra word bolded, definition italicized):

 Across
 1. Nobleman's unending expedition to populate Arctic planet: QUESt inside MARS
 6. Romeo originally named – before marriage, ultimately?: NÉ + end of marriagE &lit
 7. Ivan who served serious purpose in the middle of rebellions: END inside center of rebeLLions
 8. Entities bound to be drawn: double definition
 10. Central European city's rodeo born to be wild: BORN*
 12. Web lovers kiss behind Arthur Trudeau's back: BEA + trudeaU + X
 13. Younger water and wind coming from the east: AIR< 
 14. Tornado outflow violently takes front of farmhouse from one place to another: TORNADO* around start of Farmhouse 
 Down
 1. Somewhere in Canada, athlete guy goes against current on boat at sea: MAN + I + BOAT*
 2. Indigo caviar and pink wine – zero shillings!: ROSE - S
 3. Obnoxious and perverted guy Umberto pinched girl's bottom: GUY* around end of girL
 4. Marine ranger brings on a notable random sample: hidden in bringS ON A Random
 5. A risqué doodler scribbled to describe desirable destination: (A DOODLER)* 
 9. She inspires poets to ingest sweet? Oh, that's about right: EAT + O around R
 11. One zone failed to hold ten farm animals: ONE* around X
 13. Brits who fly a great distance to return radio: FAR<

The instruction from the extra words is:

ACROSSES ROW BY ROW AEIOU ONE REST ZERO

Following the instruction:

 In each across clue, replace consonants by 0 and vowels by 1

 The rows are 01001100, 01101000, 01100001, 01110011, 01100001. Interpreting each 8-bit string as an ASCII character we get the final answer, Lhasa!

